# Hibernate, what is the difference between "on" and "with" in a join clause?

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate, I can have a join clause:

```
from Product p
left join Family f on f.z = p.q
```

Or I can write

```
from Product p
left join Family f with f.z = p.q
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

WITH clause is used for subquery factoring and also known as common table expressions.

Syntax: WITH tempTable_Name AS (SELECT column_Name..... FROM table_Name)

ON clause is used to join columns that have different names

Syntax: SELECT * FROM table T1 LEFT JOIN table T2 ON T1.column_Name = T2.column_Name